# Is there a Javascript library that allows me to draw organisation charts left to right?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I'm working on a project where I need to render diagrams in the browser similar to this:
[image]

I've looked at a number of organisational charting tools such as the [Google Visualisations Organisation Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html) but none of them seem to let me change the orientation.

The nodes shown in the diagram above don't have to be icons, in fact I'd prefer to work with just plain old boxes where I can inject a snippet of HTML (in the same way you can do with the Google Visualisations Organisation Chart).

It would also be useful to be able to highlight a specific path through the chart, as the green lines in the example above do.

Does such a library exist?

Comment: there are free services for that thought

Comment: @yoda - that's a bit off the mark, I'm looking for a library with an API so I can generate these in code.

Answer (score 3):

One of the helpful folks over at DocType, [Ktash](http://doctype.com/users/7416), suggested I try [The JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/).

It has a visualisation called [SpaceTree](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html) which after a bit of hacking around should fit my needs.